# How can I store a closure that returns another closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm storing a callback inside a struct for later use, but I want that callback to return another callback. How can I do that?

```rust
struct Strategy {
    callback: ???
}

Strategy {
    callback: || {
        println!("{}", "strategy_init");

        return || {
            println!("{}", "strategy_update");
        }
    },
}
```

I'm trying to mimic something from Javascript:

```
const x = () => () => {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it generic:

```rust
struct Strategy<S, F>
where
    S: Fn() -> (),
    F: Fn() -> S
{
    callback: F
}

Strategy {
    callback: || {
        println!("{}", "strategy_init");

        || {
            println!("{}", "strategy_update");
        }
    },
};
```

Or store a `fn` pointer:

```
struct Strategy {
    callback: fn() -> fn() -> ()
}

Strategy {
    callback: || {
        println!("{}", "strategy_init");

        || {
            println!("{}", "strategy_update");
        }
    },
}
```

But that will restrict the closures to function-like closures that don't refer to values in their environment.

Comment: Just missing the boxed trait object way for the functional trifecta: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1c545453cd1c480f9b11680f85acc69b)) :)

Comment: I haven't learned about Box Types yet.

Comment: I also never learned about Struct X <> where {} , this is totally new to me that we can use the `where`keyword there.

Comment: @TMvytKA9LgSVZ8Z7 This is also not recommended; put the `where` on the `impl` unless the struct will not compile without them.